# deploy database table to production environment in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to deploy the asp.net mvc 3 application to production Environment from Development Environment.

**Development Environment**

1. Sql Server 2008
2. Visual Studio 2010
3. Application: ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework using Model First Approach
4. Database built in visual studio which is in .mdf format

**Production Environment:**

1. sql server 2005
2. Window Server 2008 R2
3. IIS 7

I have published application using Visual Studio to Production Environment using FTP Publish Method. When I browsed the application it throws the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.User'.

As I have not built the tables in sql server 2005 database of production environment, the above exception is throwned. Is there any easy way to deploy the database of Development environment using Visual Studio to database of Production Environment? Or Does I need to build the each and every tables manually in production environmetn?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it, Code First Migrations may be the solution that you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621.

Another way of accomplishing this is using Microsoft's SQL Server Data Tools project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx.  To get this functionality, you used to have to pay for a Visual Studio Premium or higher license, but is now free with SQL Server Data Tools.  I have worked with the approach for systems that were written with a database first approach and where maintaining a history of versioned SQL scripts is a requirement.

To use this approach, installed SSDT and create a new database project. Then create a Schema Comparison that compares your development database to the database project.  Run the comparison and write the updates to the project (For future updates, you can compare schema between your production and development database using this tool).

You can then use the Publish functionality to publish the project either directly to the production database, or to generate a script that you then verify and run by hand.

Be extra careful about publishing directly to the production database, as I would be concerned about data loss or unintended updates.  Except for the initial schema creation (and maybe not even for initial creation), I would recommend that you always generate a script so that you can verify the output and test in a stage environment before running against your production database.

I realize that you are comparing against development database schema and maintaining a separate model than your POCOs, which may not be your intent, but once you start managing releases and versioning, having a versioned set of SQL scripts that you can check into source control and refer back to is invaluable.